# .htaccess & .htpasswd equals 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I+m trying make a folder on my server protected by .htaccess & .htpasswd. When I try to enter the folder in question I'm asked for a password like I want. But then when the page is loaded I get a 500 error, which also happens on all pages on my site now. With ErrorDocument 500 it says:

This webpage has a redirect loop

The webpage at http://example.com/test/folder/ has resulted in too many redirects.
...

This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://81.18.24.170/test/appload/
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /test/folder/admin/.htpasswd 
require valid-user
```

Can anyone see a problem or something that I've missed to make it work?

EDIT: I had the rewrite rule to prevent the 301 error I get for to many redirects. (Found in another solution but it didn't help.) So I just want to get rid of the 500 error.

Comment: what happens if you remove the line : `ErrorDocument 500 http://81.18.24.170/test/appload/`

Comment: Then it gives me only the 500 error and doesn't mention to many redirects! :(

Comment: ok, what else is in your htaccess file ?

Comment: these are the only five lines I have!

Comment: I think your 500 error does not come from you htacces. if you remove the directory protection, does it work properly ? if yes, check that mod_auth is installed in apache

Comment: I just tried adding line by line and the one that gives the error is: require valid-user. I will check mod_auth.

Comment: Do you have any other .htaccess files anywhere else in the web folders? Also, if you remove this .htaccess completely do you still get a 500 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are putting the file path for the AuthUserFile, make sure you use the FULL filepath from your root directory, for example:

```
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/test/folder/admin/.htpasswd
```

A similar issue was discussed in this thread:
[htaccess / htpasswd in subdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142603/htaccess-htpasswd-in-subdir?rq=1)