# htaccess / htpasswd in subdir

Tags: php, .htaccess, password-protection, .htpasswd

im using a gallery script in root directory that reads a subdirectory and lists images inside.

```
/gallery/index.php?gallery=aaa  --> lists thumbs in folder  /gallery/aaa/thumbs/
/gallery/index.php?gallery=bbb  --> lists thumbs in folder  /gallery/bbb/thumbs/
```

Click on thumb opens the large image. Large images are in folder

```
/gallery/aaa/   -> includes htaccess/htpasswd
/gallery/bbb/   -> includes htaccess/htpasswd
```

Ive added htaccess/htpasswd protection to each image folder to give 1 user access to 1 image folder. The problem is that the password prompt appears in a loop, multiple times. Would you help to setup the protection correctly? If this cant be done, whats a good alternative?

Thanks in advance

example for dir aaa:

```
htaccess file:
AuthUserFile /gallery/aaa/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic

<limit GET POST>
require valid-user
</limit>

htpasswd file:
admin:adpexzg3FUZAk
```

Comment: Can you post the left several lines of your apache error logs, and access logs? Feel free to remove some information.

Comment: Thx, i forgot to mention the thumb directory, the logs:

"GET /gallery/aaa/thumbs/PICT0022.JPG HTTP/1.1" 401 401
admin [17/Apr/2014:23:17:00 +0200] "GET /gallery/aaa/thumbs/PICT0022.JPG HTTP/1.1" 401 401
admin [17/Apr/2014:23:17:07 +0200] "GET /gallery/aaa/thumbs/PICT0022.JPG HTTP/1.1" 401 401


[error] (2)Could not open password file: /gallery/aaa/.htpasswd, referer: http://peter.test.net/gallery/index.php?gallery=aaa
[error] user admin not found: /gallery/aaa/thumbs/PICT0022.JPG, referer: http://peter.test.net/gallery/index.php?gallery=aaa

Comment: Thanks  Justin E, the logs helped. I did not use the full path. Problem is solved.